# Can't reset setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick

I'm currently trying to create an Escape Game with Android Studio (Kotlin).
To do so, I created many XML files, one for each room, and the user must be able to move from one room to another.
In order to do that, I created a "Door" class linked to an ImageView? attribute. In "MainActivity.kt", inside "onResume", I created an array "objectList" of all the existing objects (Door, DectorativeObject, ...) of every room, then I invoke a setOnClickListener on them at every room switch (necessary because the ImageView? of every object out of the current content is null).

Unfortunately, everytime I come back to a room I already was, every object in this room stops responding to setOnClickListener, I think that when I enter a new room, the previous objects become null (logic since I change content), so does the setOnClickListener method... How can I fix this ?

Thanks for your help !

Here are the lines in "onResume()" that change content and set the onClick:

```
        fun changeContent(roomNumber: Int) {
            println("The content will be changed from room " + actualRoom.toString() + " to room " + roomNumber.toString())
            previousRoom = actualRoom
            actualRoom = roomNumber
            setContentView(roomsList[roomNumber])
            onResume() //Resume the music
        }
        println("I'm using the list objectList which has " + objectsList.size.toString() + " elements.")
        println("\n")
        for (obj in objectsList) {
            obj.getObjectName()
            println("The object " + obj.objectName + " from class " + obj.toString() + " is created.")
            obj.objectsInRooms = objectsList

            obj.image?.setOnClickListener{
                println("You just clicked on the object " + obj.objectName + " from type " + obj.toString())
                obj.onClick()
                if (obj.toString() == "com.example.escapegame.Door" && obj.locked == false) {
                    println(obj.objectName + " is a door, and you juste clicked on it.")
                    changeContent(obj.newRoom)
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the main structure of MainActivity.kt:
[Code Structure 1/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMnhV.png)

[Code Structure 2/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uHzH.png)
[Code Structure 3/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqIZj.png)

Here is "objectsList":

```
        val objectsList = arrayListOf<ObjectInRoom>(
            Door(imageDoorBlue, 2, 100, true, color="blue"), // Ne PAS changer de place !
            PickableObject(imageKeyBlue, 2, "key", "blue"), // Ne PAS changer de place !
            Door(imageDoorPurple, 3, 100, true, color="blue"), // Ne PAS changer de place !
            PickableObject(imageKeyPurple, 3, "key", "purple"), // Ne PAS changer de place !
            Door(imageDoorYellow, 4, 5, true), // Ne PAS changer de place !
            PickableObject(imageKeyYellow, 4, "key", "yellow"), // Ne PAS changer de place !
            DecorativeObject(imageChest, 3, type = "chest"),
            DecorativeObject(imagePortal, 0),
            Door(imagePortalButton, 0, 1, false),
            DecorativeObject(imageMayaTemple, 1,),
            Door(imageMayaDoor1, 1, 2, false),
            Door(imageMayaDoor2, 1, 3, false),
            DecorativeObject(imageInsideRoom1, 2),
            DecorativeObject(imageInsideRoom2, 3),
            DecorativeObject(imageInventory, numberOfRooms - 1),
            FragileObject(imageVase1, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase2, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase3, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase4, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase5, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase66, 2, "vase"), //Problème avec le nom "imageVase6"
            FragileObject(imageVase7, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase8, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase9, 2, "vase"),
            FragileObject(imageVase10, 2, "vase"),
            DecorativeObject(imageInstructionVase, 2),
            DecorativeObject(imageScroll, 3, type="scroll"),
            Door(imageDoorYellowFirst, 1, 5, true),
            DecorativeObject(imageMayaTemple3, 5),
            DecorativeObject(imageMayaTemple2, 4),
            DecorativeObject(imageMayaTemple4, 6)
        )
```

Finally, here is the class "ObjectInRoom"

````
abstract class ObjectInRoom(val image:ImageView?, val roomNumber: Int) {
    abstract val color: String
    abstract val type: String
    abstract val picked: Boolean
    var objectsInRooms: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<ObjectInRoom> = arrayListOf()
    open var locked = false
    open val newRoom = numberOfRooms
    var objectName = image.toString()
    protected var dead = false

    fun show() {
        if (!dead) image?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun hide() {
        if (!dead) image?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    open fun onClick() {
        println(this.objectName + " was clicked")
    }

    override fun toString(): String /* redéfinition de la méthode toString() définie dans la classe Object*/ {
        return javaClass.getName()
    }
    fun destroy() {
        this.hide()
        dead = true
    }
    fun getObjectName() {
        objectName = image.toString()
    }
}
```
````

Comment: hard to say without seeing more of your code. Like how are roomsList and objectsList initialized? How and when is `image` set inside the objects. I must say that you have a rather unconventional way of making this app. Usually you only call setContentView once and onResume is usually not called manually. Making every room a separate Fragment would be better I think.

Comment: roomsList is initalized before "class MainActivity":
`val roomsList = arrayListOf<Int>(R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.room1, R.layout.room2, R.layout.room3, R.layout.inventory)
`
objectList however is in onResume():
`val objectsList = arrayListOf<ObjectInRoom>(...)` (contains all the objects).
I haven't learned how to use fragments yet, I will do it as soon as possible. Thanks !

Comment: NB: "image" is initalized directly in the objects in objectsList, for instance:
`Door(image=imageDoorBlue, roomNumber=2, newRoom=3, locked=true)`

Comment: `obj.toString() == "com.example.escapegame.Door"` drew my attention. This statement would be invalid whenever you change Door class name or use proguard. Use instead `obj is com.example.escapegame.Door`
or shortly `obj is Door`

Comment: still hard to tell what's wrong without seeing more. especially the objectsList creation. My bet is those objects in it are the objects of the first time the room was entered. Thing is, that every time you do `setContentView` it creates new views even when you use a layout you used before. If you save some view in a variable after the first time you set the view, it won't exist after unless you reassign the views to the variables

Comment: Thanks for @ocos' tip. I believe that since I execute the "for" at every changeContent, it reasignes the values. I just edited my question with the main code structure.

Comment: I also just added the "ObjectInRoom" class